# Scala: lock extended class

Tags: scala, inheritance, locking, traits

I'd like to "lock" a class, which is extended from a trait. Is it possible in Scala?

For example I have:

```
trait A {
val boris: String
val john: String
val number: Int
}

class B extends A {
 // do something with these values
}
```

but can I ensure, that in class B no new values will be added if those aren't declared in trait A?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: In Scala you cannot (at least without reflection/macros). Moreover, I'm not aware of any OO language that has such mechanism.

Comment: That's sad. But actually I thought the same, that's why I've asked. May be there is some lib or workaround.

Comment: I'm curious about the design requirement that leads you to want to be able to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

But if you simply mark the trait as sealed and provide a default implementation:

```
sealed trait A { val boris: String }
final class B(val boris: String) extends A {}
```

then people are free to create implicit value classes that make it look like new functionality has been added (except without actually creating the class):

```
implicit class MyB(val underlying: B) extends AnyVal {
  def sirob = underlying.boris.reverse
}
(new B("fish")).sirob   // "hsif"
```

You can also let the classes take a type parameter as a marker if you want to keep them straight at compile-time (though not runtime):

```
sealed trait A[T] { val boris: String }
final class B[T](val boris: String) extends A[T] {}

implicit class MyB(val underlying: B[Int]) extends AnyVal {
  def sirob = underlying.boris.reverse
}
(new B[Int]("fish")).sirob   // "hsif"
(new B[Char]("fish")).sirob  // error: value sirob is not a member of B[Char]
```

So you could--especially with 2.10--simply lock everything and let users enrich the original interface this way.

I'm not sure if this covers your intended use case, though; it doesn't provide any inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example and my guess at what you are actually trying to do, you may want to consider just using case classes.

Extending a case class is generally avoided (I think it will spit out deprecation warnings if you try), so that will prevent people from wanting to extend your class in order to add functionality.

Translating your example into a case class:

```
case class A (boris: String, john: String, number: Int)
```

Then instead of extending `A` to change its values, you'd just make a new instance, e.g.

```
val a2 = someOtherA.copy(john="Doe")
```